# How do I ship the GCP cloud function app to the customer in a secure way?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have created a GCP cloud function. I can deploy the package via CLI or Console in my account. But the thing is that,  How do I ship the GCP cloud function app(package) to the customer account in a secure way?. I don't want to share the source code.

Comment: Maybe integrate your cloud function with customer's CD pipeline with delivery being done only from a specific "service account".

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Can we deploy GCP cloud function via GCP market place?

Comment: You can, but that would be to GCP market place and not to your specific customer. It has a separate set of workflow defined. Here's the procedure https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/kubernetes-solutions/submitting

Comment: why do I make it as Kubernetes-solutions?. I just need to ship and deploy the cloud function package.

Comment: A Google Cloud Function should exist on your development desktop as a directory and files with documentation. Zip the directory and send it to your customer. For security, encrypt the zip file. Using Google Cloud Marketplace is not the solution unless you have a wide audience that needs your products.

Comment: You didn't say what language the cloud function was implemented in?  I'm going to assume JavaScript.  You didn't say who you didn't want to share the source code with ... the customer?  Sounds strange ... but ok.  If you want to "hide" your source code, consider running an obfuscator over the code ... search on "JavaScript obfuscator".

Comment: I used python, yes I can use obfuscation.. But the reason is, i don't want to share the package as mail attachment.